# Validate number as a UK mobile number only using libphonenumber-for-php

Tags: php, libphonenumber

I am using libphonenumber-for-php to write a validation class that will check if a number is a UK mobile number. Anything else will fail.

```
public function validate(){
    $phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
    $carrierMapper = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberToCarrierMapper::getInstance();

    foreach ($this->phoneNumbers as $number){
        try {
            $phoneNumberObject = $phoneUtil->parse($number, 'GB');
        }catch (NumberParseException $e){
            echo $e;
        }

        $valid = $phoneUtil->isValidNumber($phoneNumberObject);
        $type = $phoneUtil->getNumberType($phoneNumberObject); 
        $carrier = $carrierMapper->getNameForNumber($phoneNumberObject, 'en');
    }
}
```

Is this all that is required? I check if it is a valid number then check if it is of the mobile number type. Is there anything else I should do to be 100% certain the passed in number is a Valid UK mobile number?

Answer (score 0):

I think the method for getting a carrier is getDescriptionForNumber. I am not a complete PHP programmer, but I use this library in Python and C and then I got the same error because of that method.